# Share image through share intent to Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp, share-intent

here is the code through which i am sharing my image or video from an adaptor to WhatsApp it was working fine but now just the toast is shown that whats app not install is there any issue in the code am I missing something?

```
public void shareWhatsapp(String type, String path, String package_name) {

        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mFragment, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(path));

        PackageManager pm = mFragment.getPackageManager();
        try {
            PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(package_name, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            sharingIntent.setType(type);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            sharingIntent.setPackage(package_name);
            mFragment.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mFragment, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

here is the listener

```
   holder.repostWhatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ModelStatus curVideo = getItem(position);
                if (curVideo.getFull_path().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    shareWhatsapp("image/jpg", curVideo.getFull_path(), "com.whatsapp");
                } else if (curVideo.getFull_path().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                    shareWhatsapp("video/mp4", curVideo.getFull_path(), "com.whatsapp");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code to share image or video to whatsapp

```
 holder.repostWhatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PdfRendererActivity.this, 
              PdfRendererActivity.this.getPackageName() + ".provider", outputFile);
        
                 if (curVideo.getFull_path().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                            shareWhatsapp("image/jpg", uri);
                        } else if (curVideo.getFull_path().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                            shareWhatsapp("video/mp4", uri);
                        } 
                    }
                });
```

> shareWhatsApp

```
void shareWhatsapp(String type, String uri)
{
Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType(type);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(share);
}
```

Comment: i have one more questtion for facebook and Instagram

Comment: if (curVideo.getFull_path().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    shareInstagram("image/jpg", curVideo.getFull_path(), "com.instagram.android");
                } else if (curVideo.getFull_path().endsWith(".mp4")) {

                    shareInstagram("video/mp4", curVideo.getFull_path(), "com.instagram.android");
                }

Comment: same code but the package is for facebook

Comment: com.facebook.katana

Comment: dont forget to mark accepted if it helped you